# VSCode highlight type error too many arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can I highlight type errors on VSCode?

For example:

```
def f(x):
    return x**2

f(x=10)

f(x=10, y=10)
```

The second function call, is using two arguments, x and y.
Is there any extension or settings to highlight the type error in the second function call?

Comment: pylance might get you that

Comment: This is not a syntax error, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could use Python's analysis tool [Pylint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters).

   [image]
2. As people suggested in the comments, we can use the extension "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)",(Please use `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` in `settings.json`.)

   [image]

Update:

1).When calling it in different functions in the `same` file:

[image]

2).When calling it in different functions in `different` files: Please use like `from b import f`

[image]

In addition, please ensure that 'Pylint' is successfully installed in the currently selected Python environment. (`pip install pylint`)

Comment: Indeed, it worked thanks. Although, something is strange. When I use in the global scope, like the example it worked. When I call a function inside another function it doesn't, Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @kaihami -I updated my answer and you could refer to it.